# JS - Passing arguments through an eventHandler

Tags: javascript, events, callback, event-handling, parameter-passing

I have a function to open a popup-window called "openPopup()". The popup has two static buttons: Cancel and Submit. The first parameter of the openPopup()-function is the content of the popup. The second parameter is a callback-function that will be binded to an click-Event on the submit-button. The problem: If the callback-function has some parameters, they are not passed to the eventHandler. In the example it's the parameter "formData":

```
function showPopup(content, callback) {
    // put content inside the popup
    // add a class the the popup so that it's visible
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener( 'click', callback);
}
```

And this is the script that runs after a user clicks on something:

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("before","popup"); // just as an example
showPopup("Hey, click me and I submit formData!>", function(formData) {
    formData.append("value","test");
    //submitting formData with Ajax...
});
```

"formData" is not undefined, it's not passed over through the Eventhandler. Instead, format is now the mouseEvent. **How can I change the code so that I can access "formData" inside the callback-function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passing behavior is written `addEventListener`, which cannot be changed if the code of  `addEventListener` is not modified.

However, note that closures are created at the moment of function definition. By writing

```
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("before","popup"); // just as an example
showPopup("Hey, click me and I submit formData!>", function() { // no parameters
    // formData is accessible here
});
```

you define the callback function while `formData` is present, so `formData` will be included in the closure. That means the exact `formData` is accessible to you when the callback function is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override getting MouseEvent as first variable but you can do this:

```
showPopup("Hey, click me and I submit formData!>", function( mouseEvent ) {

    // Your formData can be accessed from here by *this* 
    this.append("value","test");
    //submitting formData with Ajax...

}.bind( formData ));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved the problem! But what if I want to pass more than one parameter?

Comment: @yzn-pku solution is in case of that, other then that binding is better